# How to create and hold a http long connection through XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, xmlhttprequest

Let me say: I want to create a http long connection.

// nodejs code

```
router.get('/random', function (req, res, next) {
res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Connection": "keep-alive"
});

res.write("blabla\n");
});
```

// js code

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
    if (xhr.readyState == 3) {
      console.log('receive part of data' + xhr.responseText);
      setTimeout(function () {
        // ???????
        // How to send heartbeat here?
        // ???????
      }, 2000)
    }
  }

  xhr.open('get', '/random', true);
  xhr.send(null);
```

What I have tried is:

```
setTimeout(function () {
         xhr.send(null);
      }, 2000)
```

But it throw error:"Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED."

PS:I think I have created a http long connection successfully,because I can send data constantly.For example.

```
router.get('/random', function (req, res, next) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Connection": "keep-alive"
    });

    setInterval(function () {
        res.write("blabla\n");
    },1000)

});
```

Comment: I Think You need to create a live connection with [WebSocket](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)

Comment: @mortezaT Why? What I want is to create a http long connection, why should I use websocket? I think http long connection have nothing to do with websocket.

Comment: What I told is you should use `WebSocket` as a replace.